# Multiply two column on a inner Join

Tags: sql

help needed.

i want to multiply two column and display result to a  new column(totalQty). 
TotalQty= (ITY00.CMPITQTY *  MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Quantity)

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS ?

```
Select 
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.id, 
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.[Type], 
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Vendor, 
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Currency,ITY00.CMPTITNM,
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.BatchId, 
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.UserId, 
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo,
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.SiteId,
    ITY00.CMPITQTY,
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Quantity,
    MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.IntegrationFlag
From DB_37788.dbo.MPOS_GP_InvTransaction 
INNER JOIN TWCL.dbo.ITY00 ON ITY00.ITEMNMBR=MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo
Where (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo  like '%-GTYR%' ) 
OR (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo  like '%-JKOP%' ) 
And (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.SiteId  IN('MM-DC-ZZQW','MM-DC-TTYR') )
And (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.IntegrationFlag = 0 )
```

Comment: ?, by using `ITY00.CMPITQTY * MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Quantity`?. As to giving it an alias, you can use `ITY00.CMPITQTY * MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Quantity AS TotalQty`

Comment: Your example should work for SQL Server.  The other RDBMs may not accept the [alias = expression] syntax, in which case the more common [expression as alias] syntax should work.

Comment: Erm, just try it

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `Where (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo  like '%-GTYR%' 
OR MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo  like '%-JKOP%' ) ... ` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.id,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Type,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Vendor,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Currency,
       ITY00.CMPTITNM,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.BatchId,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.UserId,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.SiteId,
       ITY00.CMPITQTY,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Quantity,
       MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.IntegrationFlag,
      ITY00.CMPITQTY * MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.Quantity AS TotalQty
FROM DB_37788.dbo.MPOS_GP_InvTransaction
     INNER JOIN TWCL.dbo.ITY00 ON ITY00.ITEMNMBR = MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo
WHERE(MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo LIKE '%-GTYR%')
     OR (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.ItemNo LIKE '%-JKOP%')
     AND (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.SiteId IN('MM-DC-ZZQW', 'MM-DC-TTYR'))
     AND (MPOS_GP_InvTransaction.IntegrationFlag = 0);
```